# With gpg --verify, how do I distinguish valid signatures and valid signatures from trusted keys programmatically?

Tags: command-line, gnupg

I want to write a script that runs `gpg --verify` to check a signature.

The `gpg` command returns 1 for invalid signatures and 0 for valid ones. But it gives different output for keys that are in my trustdb and keys that aren't:

```
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
```

I want to run `gpg` in such a way that this warning is treated as an error, and without resorting to grepping the output. Is that possible?

By the way: It's fine if the solution requires me to use gpgme, but I haven't found anything related to the trustdb that looks remotely relevant in gpgme's documentation yet.

Comment: [This question](http://serverfault.com/questions/293101/validating-signature-trust-with-gpg) on ServerFault addresses the same issue.  The answers aren't great but may point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a particularly elegant solution, but it may be usable.

```
check_sig(){
    local LC_ALL=C output
    output=$(gpg --verify -- "$1" 2>&1) || return 1
    ! grep -Fqx 'gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!' <<<"$output"
}
```

Comment: It's worth to set `LC_ALL=C` environment variable so that command output is not translated to user's language.